# android Fotoapparat.io takes too long to take the picture why?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

hello i am using Fotoappart.io library https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat and all is fine, but when i want to take multiple photos i have a delay between each 2 photos about 3 second until the first one is saved. Here is my code i used to take the pictures

```
  val photoResult = fotoapparat!!.takePicture() //this code takes more than 2 second
            // Access the captured photo

            photoResult.toBitmap().whenAvailable { bitmapPhoto ->//also this one
                if (bitmapPhoto != null) {
                    val c =
                        capts().execute()//here i take the bitmap and save the photo 
                                        //into the cache...


                }
                Unit
            }
```

i need to minimize the process to the maximum to take photos quiclky any solution?